# Tutorial inside the iPad app

Tags: ios, ipad

I need some suggestion for implementing app tutorial inside my iPad app. Which gives a basic knowledge on the application and can use without training.

- I thought of making a small videos and add it to the app bundle when user taps on the demo he can see the related video. But it feel this could affect the performance of the app because my app already has lot of data.
- Adding a Demo button in the setting. When it is turned on then we orride the function of the button and we show a popover which explains the nature of the button. Example: A button which is used to open a view, when the demo button is turned on it will show a popover with detail what it does when it is tapped.

The above are the thoughts which i got to implement. Can you suggest any better ways to acheive this.

Answer (score 1):

You have asked quite broad question, This is something which entirely depends on you app design and user experience.

Most of the apps i have seen use images/wizard to introduce their features to the user. for example, in one of my what i have done is that when user runs the app for the first time than the tutorial screen pops up which has the images of all screens with all the details of what tool does what and all these images are added into a scroll view aligned horizontally with a pager control which allows the user to view all screens page by page.

To get a glimpse of what am i talking about, you can check this tutorial [UIScrollview with PageControl](http://www.iosdevnotes.com/2011/03/uiscrollview-paging/)

hope that help!

Answer (score 0):

Can you have a settings area of the app in which the user can disable or enable screen tips?